# Trying to keep a function constantly running while tkinter button is held

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I currently have a button in tkinter to run a function when the button is released. I need the button to constantly add toa number at a certain rate the entire time the button is being held.

```
global var
var=1
def start_add(event,var):
    global running
    running = True
    var=var+1
    print(var)
    return var

def stop_add(event):
    global running
    print("Released")
    running = False
button = Button(window, text ="Hold")
button.grid(row=5,column=0)
button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',start_add)
button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',stop_add)
```

i dont necessarily need any function to run when the button is released, just while the button is being held if this helps. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `while` loop...

Comment: could you clarify. if you put a while inside one of the events it runs an infinite loop cause the release of the button is not checked for each iteration.

Comment: Also note that the `global` statement is useless in the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing builtin that can do this, but it would be easy to make your own Button that can. You are on the right track too, only thing you are missing is that you need to use `after` to make the loop and `after_cancel` to stop the loop:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

class PaulButton(tk.Button):
    """
    a new kind of Button that calls the command repeatedly while the Button is held
    :command: the function to run
    :timeout: the number of milliseconds between :command: calls
      if timeout is not supplied, this Button runs the function once on the DOWN click,
      unlike a normal Button, which runs on release
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.command = kwargs.pop('command', None)
        self.timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout', None)
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.start)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.stop)
        self.timer = ''

    def start(self, event=None):
        if self.command is not None:
            self.command()
            if self.timeout is not None:
                self.timer = self.after(self.timeout, self.start)

    def stop(self, event=None):
        self.after_cancel(self.timer)

#demo code:
var=0
def func():
    global var
    var=var+1
    print(var)

root = tk.Tk()
btn = PaulButton(root, command=func, timeout=100, text="Click and hold to repeat!")
btn.pack(fill=tk.X)
btn = PaulButton(root, command=func, text="Click to run once!")
btn.pack(fill=tk.X)
btn = tk.Button(root, command=func, text="Normal Button.")
btn.pack(fill=tk.X)

root.mainloop()
```

As @rioV8 mentioned, the `after()` call is not extremely accurate. If you set the timeout to 100 milliseconds, you can usually expect anywhere from 100 - 103 milliseconds between calls. These errors will stack up the longer the button is held. If you are trying to time exactly how long the button has been held down you will need a different approach.

Comment: The final value of `var` will not be accurate. `after` will call the function "not sooner than timeout ms". The total adjustment of `var` will be less than `totaltime/timeout`. It is better to record a time at the button press and the current value of `var`, in the `after` callback (different function then `self.start`) modify var based on the real wall clock time difference and timeout and the initial `var` value: `var=self.varStart+timeDiff_ms/self.timeout`. If there is a `self.timeout` the `self.command` should not be called at the `ButtonPress` event: not been pressed for `timeout` ms.

Comment: Yes, good point @rioV8, due to known timing issues there will be a few milliseconds error in the timing for each call. This can't be used where you need super accurate timing.

Answer (score 0):

@Novel's answer should work I think, but here is something more along the lines of what you were trying, that doesn't require a whole new class:

```
from tkinter import *
INTERVAL=5 #miliseconds between runs
var=1
def run():
    global running, var
    if running:
        var+=1
        print(var)
        window.after(INTERVAL, run)

def start_add(event):
    global running
    running = True
    run()

def stop_add(event):
    global running, var
    print("Released")
    running = False

window=Tk()
button = Button(window, text ="Hold")
button.grid(row=5,column=0)
button.bind('<ButtonPress-1>',start_add)
button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',stop_add)
mainloop()
```

Comment: "that doesn't require a whole new class" is a terrible reason. Classes are awesome! As soon as you start to use them you will find yourself finding reasons to use them, rather than finding reasons to avoid them. The most obvious reason is that my class allows any number of repeating Buttons to be made.

Comment: @Novel you seem to have misunderstood me, I have been an enthusiastic python programmer for over 2 years now, and use classes frequently. I agree that they are very useful, and, in the long term, make coding much easier. This is just another answer to the the question, and that is a major difference. This code is also simpler, and along the same lines as the code from the  question, IMHO.

Comment: Nothing personal, but IMO your answer is worse than mine in every way. Classes are neater and simpler in long and short term. Also, globals are universally bad, and wildcard imports are discouraged and against PEP8. Your code is shorter, but that does not mean it's simpler, faster, or better, in fact you could argue that that makes it worse. -Programmer for over 20 years, python programmer for 6 years.

Comment: The one nice thing about your code is that it's "beginner friendly" in that beginners are often unfamiliar with classes. However I believe in baptising my students with fire, and it usually goes pretty well. After all students use classes all the time, they just don't realize that `tk.Button` and literally everything else is a class.

Comment: @Novel I was not trying to say a was a better/more experienced python programmer than you, just that I have plenty of experience of working with classes. I agree that classes a good, and should be used wherever it is more efficient, simpler, easier to understand, etc. The main reason for me for posting this answer here was, yes, because it is hopefully more easy to understand, and is closer to the code provided by the OP. I agree that your code would be better for use in most situations. Have an upvote.